# Select Only 2nd Row From Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a script I can run to only select the 2nd row of a table?

Here is what I currently have to retrieve results.

```
SELECT [Acct # (DDMA)]
 ,[Short Name (DDMA)] 
FROM [EWFImport].[dbo].[Page1$]
```

Comment: That information should be in your question, not the comments. Please use the [edit] feature to add to your questions. I have done this for you.

Comment: Thank you! I've edited it again to have the proper formatting.

Answer (score 4):

Use `offset 1 row` to skip the first row. Use `fetch first 1 row only` to get only one row, the 2:nd one.

```
SELECT [Acct # (DDMA)]
      ,[Short Name (DDMA)] 
FROM [EWFImport].[dbo].[Page1$]
ORDER BY [Acct # (DDMA)]
offset 1 row
fetch first 1 row only
```

(I chose to `ORDER BY [Acct # (DDMA)]` here, switch to other column if that suits you better.)

Comment: ...and use the `ORDER BY` clause to create the order, since a SQL table is an unordered set. (Obligatory comment.)

Comment: Here is what I'm using but I'm getting an error.

    select *
    from [EWFImport].[dbo].[Page1$]
    order by cx
    offset 1 fetch first 1 row only

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'fetch'.
Msg 153, Level 15, State 2, Line 4
Invalid usage of the option first in the FETCH statement.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why it won't let me format it correctly.

Comment: Try again, made a minor change to "offset 1 row".

Comment: I get this message now.

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'cx'.

Comment: You have to put your column name there, the one you order the result by. Perhaps [Acct # (DDMA)] or [Short Name (DDMA)].

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked. In my current table, I have 3 entries. The way you have it above is grabbing the 2nd from the list, which is what I was wanting, but how would I change it to grab the 1st or 3rd in the list if I wanted to change it? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Skip the OFFSET to fetch the first row. Do `OFFSET 2 ROW` to fetch the 3rd row.

Comment: Do I remove the entire OFFSET line to get the first one? When I did that, I got an error. Changing it to OFFSET 2 ROW did grab the 3rd entry so thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that SQL Server is special here, the only product that requires OFFSET when FETCH FIRST is used. Skip both OFFSET and FETCH FIRST, instead do `SELECT TOP 1 [Acct # (DDMA)], ...` to get the first row.

Comment: @jarlh, you have made my day (maybe even my week)! Thanks again for your help.